# whats the best way of referencing a class in object oriented programming?

Tags: oop

A good code is what every Programmer wants to write , optimized, robust, good regarding performance, re-usable, etc. I am doing programming for quite a long time in object oriented programming. I have seen many different codes in which different developers used different referencing mechanisms.

some of the developers used

```
Classname c = new Classname();
c.method();
c.method2();
```

etc...

while some developers have used following strategy

```
(new ClassName()).method();
(new ClassName()).method2();
```

I want to know whats best in both of them whats the actual difference between both of them ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Classname c = new Classname();
c.method();
c.method2();
```

Is best if you are going to reuse your object, it creates the object once before calling the methods, so it's better than

```
(new ClassName()).method();
(new ClassName()).method2();
```

Which is basically creating a new object each time you call a method.

Consider this:

```
(new ClassName()).getName(); // Returns default value John Doe
(new ClassName()).setName('Steve');
(new ClassName()).getName(); // Returns default value John Doe

Classname c = new Classname();
c.getName(); // Returns default value John Doe
c.setName('Steve');
c.getName(); // Returns Steve
```

Answer (score 1):

The second example doesn't make sense. It suggests that the `ClassName` is stateless, so you can make the methods `static`. Even if they need to use some constructor parameters (not present in your example though), then why would you instantiate an object twice, if you can do it once? In microscale, this is slower than creating the object only once. Also it doesn't help garbage collectors in memory-managed environments. Although, of course, in most scenarios these two issues are negligible.

The only case I can imagine for the second example is a bootstrapping scenario, when in your *main partition* you set up the whole application, and start it up:

```
main()
{
    (new Application(...)).Run();
}
```

There will be only one application object, and only one method needs to be called so it doesn't really matter to retain a handle to its instance. Another example, would be starting up some custom thread-class to perform some background operations:

```
{
    (new BackgroundWorkerThread(...)).Start();
}
```

I've never seen a sane example of calling two instance methods from the same class, in a way you've presented.